# Solving piecewise functions in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I attempted to solve a piecewise function in Maxima, but none of the solutions of the functions were returned:

```
piecewiseExample(x) := if (x < 5) then x*2 else x/2;

solve([piecewiseExample(x) = 4], [x]);
//result: [(if x<5 then 2*x else x/2)=4]
```

Is it possible for Maxima to obtain the solutions of an equation like this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple cases you can solve every branch everywhere and filter solutions:

```
solve_and_filter(eq, var, p):= block([so: solve(eq, var), prederror: true],
  sublist(so, lambda([c], p(rhs(c))))) $

pw_solve(pw, var):= map(lambda([L],
    solve_and_filter(first(L), var, second(L))), pw) $

/* represent piecewise equation as a list of equation-predicate pairs
   [ [eq1, pred1], [eq2, pred2], ... ] */
pw: [ [x*2 = 4, lambda([x], x< 5)],
      [x/2 = 4, lambda([x], x>=5)]] $

/* solve every `eq' and filter solutions using `pred' */
pw_solve(pw, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use numerical methods:

```
(%i1) f(x) := if (x < 5) then x*2 else x/2;
                                                      x
(%o1)                  f(x) := if x < 5 then x 2 else -
                                                      2
(%i9) find_root(f(x)-4,x,-1000,1000);
(%o9)                                 8.0
```

Comment: This only returns one of the solutions. It only returns 8, but the other solution is 2.

Comment: The hard part is finding a solution. When you have found a solution, you can search both to the left and to the right.

Comment: Would Maxima be able to find the solutions using an analytical approach instead of a numerical approach?

Comment: I am not sure - but since solve had problems with the `if`-expression, I have a hunch that the answer is no.

Comment: The algorithm `solve` uses is described in the documentation. As I read it, it says, that it solves algebraic equations that might involve functions which has an inverse. That means that it does not solve equations with `if`-expressions. Docs: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_20.html#solve